# Is there anyway we can prevent the transaction from getting rolllback when CPU time limit gets exceeded

Tags: batch, cpulimit

Can we check the limit if it's about to reach then we can just skip from that loop? Please help
Whenever the execution is getting entered in this line , it throws the cpu time limit error at this line.

```
if(newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate.size()>0)
   {
       Database.saveresult[] res=Database.update(newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate,false);
       if(res.size()>0)
            {
               for(Integer i=0; i < res.size(); i++) 
               {
                          if(!res.get(i).isSuccess())
                           {
                             Database.Error errors =  res.get(i).getErrors().get(0);
                             Event_Tracker__c erlog=new Event_Tracker__c();
                             erlog.Error_Description__c='Invoice Updation failed for SA=BA'+'\n'+String.valueof(res.get(i).getErrors().get(0))+'\n'+newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i];
                             erlog.name='Script 2 - 2 ST_DataTransformationBatch Script has error';
                             erlog.Error_Object__c=newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i].Opportunityid;
                             erlog.recordtypeid=evtrecordtypeid;
                             errorlogsList.add(erlog); 
                             scriptfailedoptId.add(newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i].Opportunityid);                                                 
                           }

                }
            } 

   }
```

How can I resolve this , please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a couple of things in relation to observing CPU usage in a transaction.

1. Define a CPU threshold which will provide you headroom while executing the logic.
2. Add `debug` statements to help understand the expense to CPU
3. Constantly check the CPU consumption using the [Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) class

Note, you should really spend time finding out what is causing unnecessary CPU consumption across the entire transaction as adding the conditional logic will not improve the architecture.

```
private Integer cpuTime;
private Integer cpuTimeLimit = 10000;
private Integer cpuTimeThreshold = 1000;


if (newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate.size() > 0) {
    Database.saveresult[] res = Database.update(newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate, false);
    if (res.size()>0) {
        for (Integer i=0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            cpuTime = Limits.getCpuTime();
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'CPU Used: ' + cpuTime);
            if (!res.get(i).isSuccess() && cpuTime < (cpuTimeLimit - cpuTimeThreshold)) {
                Database.Error errors =  res.get(i).getErrors().get(0);
                Event_Tracker__c erlog=new Event_Tracker__c();
                erlog.Error_Description__c='Invoice Updation failed for SA=BA'+'\n'+String.valueof(res.get(i).getErrors().get(0))+'\n'+newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i];
                erlog.name='Script 2 - 2 ST_DataTransformationBatch Script has error';
                erlog.Error_Object__c=newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i].Opportunityid;
                erlog.recordtypeid=evtrecordtypeid;
                errorlogsList.add(erlog); 
                scriptfailedoptId.add(newOLIListSameAddressInvUpdate[i].Opportunityid);                                                 
            } else {
                // Proceed with end of transaction and possibly report any unprocessed records
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks TSmith. Could you please also let me know how to iterate database.saveresult in batch Start method.